# How to start linux systemd service in C# programmatically on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: c#, linux, systemd, .net-6.0, ubuntu-20.04

I have a very simple question:
How to start / stop a systemd service from a .NET 6.0 Console App?
Just to clarify: I do *not* want the service to stop itself. I want a console app to stop another service already installed on a Ubuntu Server 20.04.

More concrete: How would I call this line in C# properly?

```
sudo systemctl start SERVICE_NAME
```

Do I have to start a Process like this?

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = " /usr/lib/systemd"
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "start SERVICENAME";
process.Start();
```

**What have I tried so far?**

I googled but could not find any viable solution, and since I am no expert on Linux I might have fallen into the [XY trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: If this is XY then why do you want to start the service from c# code. In other words if Y is you trying to run `systemctl start SERVICE_NAME` from c# code, X is?

Comment: @PabloRecalde That's not what I meant. I am asking about calling systemd service start, but maybe the root problem lies somewhere else (e.g. there is another component from Linux, that allows me to start / stop services).

Comment: XY problem is basically you coming here asking how to do Y, in order to fix X problem. As you're asking for how to start a service (Y). I'm asking you why do you want to do that for (x)

Comment: @PabloRecalde It's a .NET 6.0 console app which has to stop a service, overwrite files within service directory of a custom software and then start the service. It's an installer console app which will also upgrade database and do other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done this before. I like .NET and I use netcore every day but, if you want to create a script to be run only on linux. Maybe a `bash` script would do.

Since you want to use .NET, I think you'll need to do something like:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/bin/bash", Arguments = "systemctl stop SERVICE", }; 
Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
proc.Start();
```

You're creating a bash instance from where you call systemctl.

You also might want to wait until the process has finished. You can do that with

```
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Be aware this is a synchronous waiting.

Comment: Agreed on using a bash script or a better tool for this job. That said, you shouldn't need to exec `/bin/bash` when you can exec `/usr/bin/systemctl` directly. Calling it via bash doesn't do anything. There's also no need for `&& exit` since bash run with arguments to run other program will run those programs and then exit.